# How to ask for confirmation in toastr before deletion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm working in PHP LARAVEL , what i want is a toastr to delete an item from database.
So when the button is clicked to delete, the toastr should ask "Are you sure to delete?" in ajax.
If selected "OK" the data should be deleted, if selected "Cancel" the data should not be deleted.
How to accomplish this?

Below is my ajax code:

```
//to unfollow feed
    $('#following').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("#unfollowFeed").serialize();
        $('.error-msg').html('');
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: baseUrl + 'unfollow',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                var id=$('#feed_id').val();
                $("#feedId li[feed-id=" + id + "]").remove();    //to remove <li> of removed feed from sidebar.
                toastr.error('The feed was removed.'); 
                $('#follow').show();
                $('#following').hide();

            }

        });
    });
```

This is my view part:

```
<a href style="{{ $status == 0 ? 'display:none;' : '' }}" class=" btn btn-sm btn-primary following" id="following" >{{ __('Following') }}</a>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can use confirm box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Example: Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var r = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use the inbuilt confirm box:

```
 $('#following').click(function (e) {
var response = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");
  if (response == true) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("#unfollowFeed").serialize();
        $('.error-msg').html('');
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: baseUrl + 'unfollow',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                var id=$('#feed_id').val();
                $("#feedId li[feed-id=" + id + "]").remove();    //to remove <li> of removed feed from sidebar.
                toastr.error('The feed was removed.'); 
                $('#follow').show();
                $('#following').hide();

            }

        });

  } else {
    /* do anything on Pressed cancel*/
  }

    });
```

Comment: i edited like you said, but the else case is not working...showing this error: "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." but i have given POST in ajax as well as in web.php:                                                                                                  else {
        toastr.success('Your feed is safe!');
    }

Comment: It is not about the confirm box. It is related to the laravel, you need to check the Network tab for the request method and also need to check the POST URL, it is correct or not

Comment: Was it working earlier? before you implemented confirm box?

Comment: Try again without adding the confirm box. I'm sure there is something missing while adding the confirmbox code.

Comment: Hey thanks! i got it, was just a small mistake; should have given "return false" in else part....now it's working. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sweetalert](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/) of bootstrap

```
$('#following').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("#unfollowFeed").serialize();
        $('.error-msg').html('');
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function() {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: baseUrl + 'unfollow',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    var id=$('#feed_id').val();
                    $("#feedId li[feed-id=" + id + "]").remove();    //to remove <li> of removed feed from sidebar.
                    toastr.error('The feed was removed.'); 
                    $('#follow').show();
                    $('#following').hide();

                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sweetalert for this purpose.

[Sweet alert docs](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

Add this cdn `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`

then

```
<script>
   $('#following').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary 
               file!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
     if (willDelete) {

      ajaxcall(); //calling ajax function
      swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
 });

});

function ajaxcall()
{
  $('.error-msg').html('');
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: baseUrl + 'unfollow',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            var id=$('#feed_id').val();
            $("#feedId li[feed-id=" + id + "]").remove();    //to remove <li> of removed feed from sidebar.
            toastr.error('The feed was removed.'); 
            $('#follow').show();
            $('#following').hide();

        }

    });
}

</script>
```